# Different value computed on VS and gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-c++

For the following code `lval` is computed to be a different value on VS and gcc.

**Code :**

```
const double val = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
const unsigned long lval = (std::numeric_limits<decltype(val)>::infinity() == val || (static_cast<unsigned long>(val) >= 2)) ?
    std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max() :
    999;
cout << lval;
```

**On Visual Studio**

`lval` is computed to be 999

http://rextester.com/EMFL77801

**On g++**

`lval` is computed to be 18446744073709551615

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/682c81bbe498ddc5

**Question**

Why are these two values different?

**Furthermore**

I tried the same code in stand-alone gcc, and put a breakpoint in gdb. I saw that `static_cast<unsigned long>(val) >= 2` evaluated to `true` on gdb, but the same expression evaluated to be `false` in VS

Comment: I'm pretty sure a conversion from floating point to integeral type that produces a result out of range for the latter - as in `static_cast<unsigned long>(val)` - exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> § 4.9.1 Floating-integral conversions
>
> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates;
> that is, the fractional part is discarded. **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be
> represented in the destination type.**

`std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` can't fit into an `unsigned long` so the behavior is undefined and the compiler can do whatever it wants.

Apparently in the visual studio case `static_cast<unsigned long>(val) >= 2` returns false.

Answer (score -1):

On a 64 but platform gcc gives long 64 bits, and visual studio gives it 32 bits.